# My favicon is not showing up on the browser. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, web, favicon

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Asem Syed</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.png" type="image/png"  />

</head>
<body>
    <div><h1>aasemjs.com will be live.</h1></div>
    <div><h1>...soon.</h1></div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my short code, my favicon has been uploaded in the public_html directory, as well as a folder in that "images". On the browser it keeps showing me a broken link.

What am I doing wrong over here?

Comment: What is the actual URL of the request being made by the browser?  Does that URL match where the file is on the web server?

Comment: Check folder name, is it image or images?

Comment: Try `href="images/favicon.png"`

Comment: as you can read on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) it is better to use the .ico format for greater support of web browsers. You can try to use an absolute path (/folder/favicon.png)

Answer (score 0):

This code should help you out.
If you have the css in a folder use "../", if this doesn't work just stick with "/" in front of images.

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/images/picture.png">
```

If you put "sizes" in the link tag, it won't be supported by any browsers, so you'll have to change the width and height in a photo editor.